# Sqlite database saved as file

Tags: android, database, sqlite, dropbox

I've build an app for managing transactions and i'm currently adding dropbox backup. I do this by uploading the databasefiles to dropbox (which seems to be appearing correctly). Then i want to download the files again and overwrite the existing databases. When i do this the databases get saved as files ei. get listed by context.fileList(); instead of context.databaseList(); How do i handle the database files to get them in the right place?

Here is the code i thought relevant:

```
private static class Downloader extends AsyncTask<Integer, Integer, Boolean>{
    Context context;
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute(){
        context = SpendoBase.getContext();
    }
    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Integer... arg0) {
        System.out.println("DoInBackground:");
        try {
            List<DropboxAPI.Entry> entries = mDBApi.metadata("/", -1, null, true, null).contents;
            File file;
            FileOutputStream os;
            int count = 0;
            for(DropboxAPI.Entry entry: entries){
                count++;
                System.out.println("Entry.path(): " + entry.path  + " " + count + "/" + entries.size());
                file = new File(entry.path);
                System.out.println("1");
                os = context.openFileOutput(file.getName(), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                System.out.println("2");
                DropboxFileInfo info = mDBApi.getFile(entry.path, null, os, null);
                os.flush();
                os.close();
                System.out.println("3 " + info);
            }

        } catch (DropboxException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }
}

private static class Uploader extends AsyncTask<Integer, Integer, Boolean>{
    String[] databaseList;
    Context context;
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute(){
        context = SpendoBase.getContext();
        databaseList = context.databaseList();
    }
    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Integer... params) {
        for(String dbName: databaseList){
            try {
                File f = context.getDatabasePath(dbName);
                FileInputStream  fis = new FileInputStream(f.getPath());
                mDBApi.putFileOverwrite("/" + dbName, fis, f.length(), null);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (DropboxException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

} 
private static class MetaReader extends AsyncTask<Integer, Integer, List<String>>{

    @Override
    protected List<String> doInBackground(Integer... arg0) {
        try {

            List<String> result = new Vector<String>();
            DropboxAPI.Entry existingEntry = mDBApi.metadata("/", -1, null, true, null);
            List<DropboxAPI.Entry> temp = existingEntry.contents;
            for(int i = 0; i < temp.size(); i++){
                File f = new File(temp.get(i).path);
                result.add(f.getName());
            }
            return result;
         } catch (DropboxException e) {
             System.out.println("Something went wrong: " + e);
         }
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<String> result){
        for(String str:result){
            System.out.println(str);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't do much Android development, so I could be way off base here, but why can't you just use `context.getDatabasePath(dbName)` again in the `Downloader` and write the file to that path?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve it. My error was simply that I saved the database in the wrong place.

Changing:

```
 file = new File(entry.path);
            System.out.println("1");
            os = context.openFileOutput(file.getName(), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

to:

```
  file = new File("/data/data/com.SverkerSbrg.SpendoFull/databases/" + entry.path);
                System.out.println("1");
                os = new FileOutputStream(file.getPath());
```

Solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

You need to root your target phone to save your file on /data/data/com.SverkerSbrg.SpendoFull/databases/ this location.

Comment: You can directly store any file on internal or external storage. Please take help from http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html to store a file.